# How to include at will text in certain parts of the footer of some slides

Tags: beamer, footer

I am trying to include some authors and journal information about a paper in the footer of **certain** slides of my beamer presentation. In the beamer madrid default style framework, I would want to put the authors centered in the region with the darkest blue, and the journal in the middle teal box (see attached image to see which regions I mean).
[image]

The preamble of my beamer looks like this:

```
\documentclass[professionalfont,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{outlines}

\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\def\scalecheck{\resizebox{\widthof{\checkmark}*\ratio{\widthof{x}}{\widthof{\normalsize x}}}{!}{\checkmark}}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{foot1}{<define footer 1 here>}
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{foot2}{<define footer 2 here>}

\graphicspath{
{./Figures/}
}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{-0pt}
}

\newcommand{\backupbegin}{
   \newcounter{framenumberappendix}
   \setcounter{framenumberappendix}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
   \addtocounter{framenumberappendix}{-\value{framenumber}}
   \addtocounter{framenumber}{\value{framenumberappendix}} 
}


%\addmediapath{./Figures/}

\newcommand{\stkout}[1]{\ifmmode\text{\sout{\ensuremath{#1}}}\else\sout{#1}\fi}

\newcommand{\di}{\mathrm{i}}

\newcommand{\iu}{\mathrm{i}\mkern1mu}

\newcommand*{\I}{\imath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\rchi}{{\mathpalette\irchi\relax}}
\newcommand{\irchi}[2]{\raisebox{\depth}{$#1\chi$}}

\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbullet}
\makeatother

\def\mathcolor#1#{\@mathcolor{#1}}
\def\@mathcolor#1#2#3{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\title[]{TITLE}
\date{}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `\author` and `\title` just for the frames which should have the special text in the footline:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% that's the default
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
%\usepackage{amssymb}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
%\usepackage{amsthm}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
%\usepackage{amsmath}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
%\usepackage{graphicx,color}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
\usepackage{multimedia}
%\usepackage{float}% makes no sense with beamer
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{upgreek}
%\usepackage{hyperref}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
%\usepackage{hyperref}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{amsthm}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
%\usepackage{amssymb}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage{upgreek}% you've already loaded this package
%\usepackage{textcomp% you've already loaded this package}
%\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}% you've already loaded this package
%\usepackage{textcomp}% you've already loaded this package
%\usepackage{float}% you've already loaded this package
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{times}% obsolete, use e.g. the mathptmx, helvet (option scaled=.9) or courier packages
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
%\usepackage{color}% beamer automatcially loads this for you
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{outlines}

\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\def\scalecheck{\resizebox{\widthof{\checkmark}*\ratio{\widthof{x}}{\widthof{\normalsize x}}}{!}{\checkmark}}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{foot1}{<define footer 1 here>}
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{foot2}{<define footer 2 here>}

\graphicspath{
{./Figures/}
}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{-0pt}
}

\newcommand{\backupbegin}{
   \newcounter{framenumberappendix}
   \setcounter{framenumberappendix}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
   \addtocounter{framenumberappendix}{-\value{framenumber}}
   \addtocounter{framenumber}{\value{framenumberappendix}} 
}


%\addmediapath{./Figures/}

\newcommand{\stkout}[1]{\ifmmode\text{\sout{\ensuremath{#1}}}\else\sout{#1}\fi}

\newcommand{\di}{\mathrm{i}}

\newcommand{\iu}{\mathrm{i}\mkern1mu}

\newcommand*{\I}{\imath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\rchi}{{\mathpalette\irchi\relax}}
\newcommand{\irchi}[2]{\raisebox{\depth}{$#1\chi$}}

\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbullet}
\makeatother

\def\mathcolor#1#{\@mathcolor{#1}}
\def\@mathcolor#1#2#3{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\title[]{TITLE}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

{
\author{P. Wells et al}
\title{Nature}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]